# Loop over array inside where statement in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using following code sample, but I cannot modify it correctly.
For example I have an array of 3 strings : 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'. And I'm searching on three stringed columns to be 'like' parts in the source array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc').
This array is created from the source string "aaa bbb ccc" by splitting on " ".

But if I get an array with more strings, this code should be different.

How could this be solved?

```
select * 
from osm_data_test."import".osm_buildings
WHERE
    (city like ('%aaa%') or street like ('%aaa%') or housenumber like ('%aaa%'))
    and
    (city like ('%bbb%') or street like ('%bbb%') or housenumber like ('%bbb%'))
    and
    (city like ('%ccc%') or street like ('%ccc%') or housenumber like ('%ccc%'))
```

Example of table.

```
id | city     | street    | housenumber
---+----------+-----------+------------
1  | NY       | Kek       | Lowl
2  | DS       | oom       | Roflan
3  | kapaaa   | bbbaby    | ccclown
4  | Maaage   | rombbb    | mocccy
5  | Maaage   | romb      | mocccy
```

The result should be 3rd and 4th rows. 5th row should not be included in result.
The expected result should be from rows, where all strings from source array are in columns city, street and housenumber.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Are you looking for e.g.: `where city like any (array['%aaa%', '%bbb%', '%ccc%') and street like any (array['%aaa%', '%bbb%', '%ccc%')`?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way which I think can be implemented but not sure about performance:

```
select * 
from osm_data_test."import".osm_buildings
WHERE
    REPLACE(REPLACE(city,'aaa','ccc'),'bbb','ccc') like ('%ccc%') or 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(street,'aaa','ccc'),'bbb','ccc') like ('%ccc%') or
    REPLACE(REPLACE(housenumber,'aaa','ccc'),'bbb','ccc') like ('%ccc%');
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select ob.*
from osm_data_test."import".osm_buildings ob
where (select count(distinct u.el) = max(array_length(a.ar, 1))
       from (values (array['a', 'b', 'c'])) a(ar) cross join
            unnest(a.ar) u(el)
       where ob.city like '%' || u.el || '%' or
             ob.street like '%' || u.el || '%' or
             ob.housenumber like '%' || u.el || '%'
      )
```